# extracting non homogeneous sequential data from xml files in an container

Tags: c++, xml, dom, containers, msxml

I am trying to extract information groups of different data type from XML file using MSXML6 DOM parser in C++. the xml contains the groups of non homogeneous data containign different data types. I would like to retrieve the different groups of the information clusters in a sequencial format. Which kind of containers is the best here?

Here is the xml file:

```
<Activity ActivityType = "CENFsfIgpSurfaceActivity" ActivityVendor = "CENIT" Operation = "Operation.1" SimEventType = "CENITEvent" id = "_-18944736">
            <ActivityName>Surface Activity.1</ActivityName>
            <Relation>Unknown</Relation>
            <Event>
                <Syntax>C_VARPUT/JOG_MOTIONTYPE,R8,1</Syntax>
                <Syntax>C_VARPUT/JOG_INTERPOLMODE,R8,0</Syntax>
                <Syntax>C_VARPUT/JOG_SERIAL,R8,0</Syntax>
                <Syntax>JOG/ -0.4125375, -1.6436356, 1.7844436, 4.2006409, 0.7993971, 0.5876199, 1.8000000</Syntax>
                <Syntax>CONFIG/ 0</Syntax>
            </Event>
        </Activity>
        <Activity ActivityType = "DNBRobotMotionActivity" ActivityVendor = "CENIT" Operation = "Operation.1" SimEventType = "IGRIPMove" id = "_-18944736">
            <ActivityName>Surface Activity.1</ActivityName>
            <Target Default = "Cartesian" ViaPoint = "false">
                <BaseWRTWorld>
                    <Position Units = "m" X = "29.672426" Y = "0.5679999981" Z = "-0.776"/>
                    <Orientation Pitch = "0" Roll = "0" Units = "deg" Yaw = "-180"/>
                </BaseWRTWorld>
                <CartesianTarget>
                    <Position Units = "m" X = "-0.676426" Y = "-0.5004420167" Z = "1.046498163"/>
                    <Orientation Pitch = "0" Roll = "0" Units = "deg" Yaw = "92.98016434"/>
                    <Config Name = "Posture_1"/>
                    <Tag TrackTag = "false">Pt.15104</Tag>
                </CartesianTarget>
                <JointTarget>
                    <Joint DOFNumber = "1" JointName = "J1" JointType = "Rotational" Units = "deg">
                        <JointValue>-23.6367</JointValue>
                    </Joint>
                    <Joint DOFNumber = "2" JointName = "J2" JointType = "Rotational" Units = "deg">
                        <JointValue>-94.1734</JointValue>
                    </Joint>
                    <Joint DOFNumber = "3" JointName = "J3" JointType = "Rotational" Units = "deg">
                        <JointValue>102.2411</JointValue>
                    </Joint>
                    <Joint DOFNumber = "4" JointName = "J4" JointType = "Rotational" Units = "deg">
                        <JointValue>240.6790</JointValue>
                    </Joint>
                    <Joint DOFNumber = "5" JointName = "J5" JointType = "Rotational" Units = "deg">
                        <JointValue>45.8021</JointValue>
                    </Joint>
                    <Joint DOFNumber = "6" JointName = "J6" JointType = "Rotational" Units = "deg">
                        <JointValue>-326.3319</JointValue>
                    </Joint>
                    <AuxJoint DOFNumber = "7" JointName = "Command.1" JointType = "Translational" Type = "RailTrackGantry" Units = "m">
                        <JointValue>1.8</JointValue>
                    </AuxJoint>
                </JointTarget>
            </Target>
            <MotionAttributes>
                <MotionProfile>Default</MotionProfile>
                <ToolProfile>End-Effector Spray Gun-Combo.1.Tool1</ToolProfile>
                <AccuracyProfile>Default</AccuracyProfile>
                <ObjectFrameProfile>Default</ObjectFrameProfile>
                <MotionType>Linear</MotionType>
            </MotionAttributes>
        </Activity>
```

Iam trying to gather each different activity in one container in the sequence.
can CArray of Union of Structs work?

Comment: Do you have a fixed set of data types that could be present, or could it be literally anything?

Comment: yes, i have fixed set of structures. the nodes can be any of the defined structures.

Comment: Well [boost::variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/variant.html) would be my choice to handle the different structures. Then whatever standard container type fits your needs e.g. `std::vector`. There's no need at all for MS specific types like `CArray`

Comment: Thanks john for your reply